# Synchronize ValueAxis grids

Tags: amcharts

I have these two `ValueAxes`:

```
{
    ...
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 100,
    strictMinMax: true,
    autoGridCount: false,
    gridCount: 10
},
{
    ...
    minimum: -15,
    maximum: 215,
    strictMinMax: true,
    autoGridCount: false,
    gridCount: 10
}
```

Now the grid lines of both axes are creating a total mess in the chart and its hard to not get confused while trying to read values. The reason for this is, that AmCharts rounds the labels up or down to ten-steps, not respecting the `gridCount`.

I need to know if there's a way to get AmCharts to stop trying to round the labels. I'm totally fine to have numbers like `62` as a label, as long as it reduces the amount of grid lines.

Comment: Sth. like setting the step manually. In my case it would be `10` for the first axis and `23` for the second one.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no way to do that in amCharts. The step is auto-calculated and is always in magnitudes of ten for value ranges that are bigger than 10.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was expecting this answer so made I already made a work-around by myself.

Comment: If that is a clever workaround, maybe you could post it as an answer for other people looking for the same solution?

Comment: Hm, well i just added an option `strictGridCount` to `valueAxis` and if it's set to `true` im just overwriting the old `min/max` and `step` to my wishes (inside `valueAxis.draw()`). Thats all.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this is a problem somewhere else, but my test are working so far.

Comment: Oh OK, so you're modifying the code for the charts. Got it. Cool :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87487/discussion-between-martynasma-and-gerric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is pretty easy.
I introduced a new option, so that the normal `strictMinMax` will still work: `strictGridCount`
I used the implementation of `strictMinMax` and added these lines just a few lines above the place where `strictMinMax` is used:

```
if(_this.strictGridCount) {
    if (!isNaN(_this.minimum)) {
        _this.min = _this.minimum;
    }

    if (!isNaN(_this.maximum)) {
        _this.max = _this.maximum;
    }

    _this.step = (_this.max - _this.min) / _this.gridCount;
}
```